# Is this problem worked out correctly?

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

> Calls are received at a company call center according to a Poisson process at the rate of five calls per minute.
>   (a) Find the probability that no call occurs over a 30-second period.
>   (b) Find the probability that exactly four calls occur in the 1st minute, and six calls occur in the second minute.
>   (c) Find the probability that 25 calls are received in the 1st 5 minutes and six of those calls occur in the 1st minute.

**My solution:**

(b) $P(N_1=4, N_2=6) \\= P(N_1=4)\cdot P(N_2=6) \\= ...$

As far as I understand, the problem talks about two different time spans. So, $(N_1=4)$ and $(N_2=6)$ should be independent.

Another notion could be:

$P(N_1=4, N_2=6) \\= P(N_1=4, N_2 - N_1 = 6) \\= P(N_1=4, N_1=6) \\=P(N_1=4) \cdot P(N_1=6)$

Which one is correct and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first need to clear out your notation. $N_t$ is the number of calls by time $t$. If the time unit is taken as minutes, $N_1$ refers to number of calls in the first minute. So, four calls in the first minute can be formulated as $N_1=4$, and six calls in the second minute can be formulated as $N_2-N_1=6$. The question is (b) is to find $P(N_1=4\cap N_2-N_1=6)=P(N_1=4\cap N_2=10)$, **not** $P(N_1=4\cap N_2=6)$. So, the *second line* in your *second method* is the correct question. Number of events occurring in *non-overlapping* time intervals are independent by the definition of Poisson Process. So, $N_1$ and $N_2-N_1$ are independent (not $N_1$ and $N_2$), which yields:

$$P(N_1=4\cap N_2-N_1=6)=P(N_1=4)P(N_2-N_1=6)$$

Here, we can write $P(N_2-N_1=6)=P(N_1=6)$ because we're interested in $6$ calls occurring in some one-minute interval, which is equivalent to asking for probability of $6$ calls in the first minute. Your final result in the second method is correct, although the way you reach it is wrong due to the reasons I've provided above.